# Why does MongoDB count query sometimes uses IXSCAN, explain shows COUNT_SCAN?

Tags: mongodb

I found that a count query with two parameters was taking longer than expected on our production database. I added an index (which took a few hours, this collection has over 100 million documents) that had both fields, which improved the results of my .explain() call from IXSCAN to COUNT_SCAN.

Looking at the logs now, I see that there are still tons of IXSCAN planSummaries for this count query:

> 2019-07-17T13:02:34.561+0000 I COMMAND  [conn25293] command
>   DatabaseName.CollectionName command: count { count: "CollectionName",
>   query: { userId: "5a4f82d4e4b09d5e0cdbae15", status: "FINISHED" } }
>   planSummary: IXSCAN { userId: 1 } keysExamined:299 docsExamined:299
>   numYields:7 reslen:44 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 16 } },
>   Database: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r:
>   8 } } } protocol:op_query 124ms

There is an index on the userId field, but I don't understand why this count query isn't hitting my new index. Here's the explain results:

```
db.CollectionName.explain().count({ userId: "59adb07de4b00782f7620c11", status: "FINISHED" })

/* 1 */
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "DatabaseName.CollectionName",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [ 
                {
                    "status" : {
                        "$eq" : "FINISHED"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "userId" : {
                        "$eq" : "59adb07de4b00782f7620c11"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COUNT",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "COUNT_SCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "userId" : 1.0,
                    "status" : 1.0
                },
                "indexName" : "idx_userId_status",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "userId" : [],
                    "status" : []
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "startKey" : {
                        "userId" : "59adb07de4b00782f7620c11",
                        "status" : "FINISHED"
                    },
                    "startKeyInclusive" : true,
                    "endKey" : {
                        "userId" : "59adb07de4b00782f7620c11",
                        "status" : "FINISHED"
                    },
                    "endKeyInclusive" : true
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : []
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "ip-10-114-1-8",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.4.16",
        "gitVersion" : "0d6a9242c11b99ddadcfb6e86a850b6ba487530a"
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

Checking the index stats, I see that it has been used quite a bit

```
{
    "name" : "idx_userId_status",
    "key" : {
        "userId" : 1.0,
        "status" : 1.0
    },
    "host" : "ip-address:27017",
    "accesses" : {
        "ops" : NumberLong(541337),
        "since" : ISODate("2019-07-16T14:34:25.281Z")
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that this means it is used sometimes, but for some reason not used at other times. Why would that be the case?

Comment: "3.4.16" was pretty old version even in July - have you considered upgrading?  In any case, once you have the compound index on userId, status, you no longer need the index just on userId, so if you drop it, all your queries will use the "better" index.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding of query planning in MongoDB, the DB keeps some kind of cache of query planning to be able to chose the right one without much thinking.
My guess is, in the case of the `IXSCAN`, the DB thought that using this one or the other wouldn't make that much of a difference.

That being said, you can still use the `explain(true)` (or more exactly `explain("allPlansExecution"`) that will try to execute all possible plans. And then if you analyze the `executionTimeMillis`, you might see some difference that would explain the choice of the query planning.

Hope this helps :)